# Can I overwrite MATLAB 2013 over 2012?

Tags: matlab

I have MATLAB 2012 installed on my laptop, but due to some toolbox issues I want to install MATLAB 2013.

I know that I can't uninstall MATLAB, I've to delete that folder.

But it is possible that I just overwrite the existing MATLAB with the new one, this will work?

Comment: Why can't you uninstall MATLAB? Unfortunately my PC with MATLAB is not here to check. The most important think it to keep the hidden .matlab folder in HOME as that has all your settings in it.

Comment: http://www.mathworks.in/help/install/ug/remove-uninstall-mathworks-products.html

Will this work?

Answer (score 1):

If you install the new version, it will not overwrite the old one, because each version uses its own folder, usually with a name of the form `R201??` under `/opt/MATLAB/`. The same holds for the settings, which are kept in a folder of the same name under `~/.matlab/`. This way it is possible to use in parallel two or more different versions of Matlab.

The "command" `matlab` is usually a symbolic link in `/usr/local/bin/` which points to the actual binary, e.g.

```
/usr/local/bin/matlab -> /opt/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/matlab
```

If you want to start another version, you have to type the full pathname of the executable at the command line, e.g.

```
$ /opt/MATLAB/R2012b/bin/matlab
```

If you only want to use the new version though, I'd recommend to uninstall the old version first. Uninstallation is done by deleting the installation directory with all its contents, and all the symbolic links pointing into that directory in `/usr/local/bin/`. Besides `matlab`, there can be e.g. `mex` or links to other executables. The [link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/install/ug/remove-uninstall-mathworks-products.html#bspf_nm-6) you provided says essentially the same, except for additional information on (de-) activating a Matlab license.